# How to remove a launcher from a Gnome Panel?

Tags: launcher, gnome-classic

My kids put some bogus launcher on top bar (I have no idea how) :

[image: launcher on top bar]

How can I remove it? I get only next options : `properties` and `launch`.

Comment: Don't judge your kids too hard for this.  I just did it too by accidentally by trying to drag a JPG up to the tabs in Chrome.  I dragged it a tiny bit too far and it left a little launcher exactly like this one and I couldn't figure it out either.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Make sure that your cursor is not pointing to the launcher. Then, hold down the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Windows key both. Right-click on the launcher then select 'Remove from Panel'.

Comment: I never would have though of that either. I added a launcher myself and couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. How about just adding "remove" to the right click context menu? Right now it only has "Launch" and "Properties".

Comment: From an anonymous user(not the person who posted this): Note: You may need to press the Super key (= Windows-Key) at the same time on some systems, i.e. hold down both the left Alt key and the Windows key before right-clicking.

Comment: Why design in that way? It's very confusing.

Comment: Great tip! I spent about 30 minutes for finding a way to remove it!

Comment: Aaaah :) The intuitiveness is so overwhelming :) :)

Answer (score 36):

The latest version of Gnome Classic (Apr 2012, at least for me) requires:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super (Windows)</kbd> and right-click.

Comment: Thanks man, this was the right answer for me. I guess this varies among versions.

Comment: works on ubuntu 13.10 :)

Comment: works on my 14.04

Comment: Wait, how is that not a copy of Anonymous's answer?